# how to make all elements invisible in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, single-page-application

I'm using the navigo vanilla javascript router library to make a single page application and I'm trying to implement this part.

```
router
  .on('/products/list', function () {
    // display all the products... here i need to hide and show
  })
  .resolve();
```

I thought the thing I need to do is hide and show some divs so how do i set all divs as invisible or make everything on the page invisible.

```
<body>
    <div id="homepage">
        <h1>home</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="ad">
        <h1>advert</h1>

    </div>
    <div id="errorpage">
        <h1>error</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="state">
        <span class="users">?</span> online
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/navigo@7.1.2/lib/navigo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: `someElement.style.display='none'` - hard to say what `someElement` would be, since you haven't shown much at all in the question

Comment: i've got the whole document.querySelector(".tag").style bit but how do i select all elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide `DIV` using id

```
 <div id="homepage">
        <h1>home</h1>
</div>
```

**using JQuery**

```
$('#homepage').hide();//hide
$('#homepage').show();//Show
```

**Using Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('homepage').style.display = 'none'; //hide
document.getElementById('homepage').style.visibility = 'hidden';      // hide


document.getElementById('homepage').style.display = 'block';          // Show
document.getElementById('homepage').style.display = 'inline';         // Show
document.getElementById('homepage').style.display = 'inline-block';   // Show
document.getElementById('homepage').style.visibility = 'visible';     // Show
```

If you want to hide all the `div` in page

**Using JQuery**

```
$('div').hide();//hide
```

**Using Javascript**

```
var divs = ​document.getElementsByTagName("div");​
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].style.display = 'none';        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most efficient way would be putting the products in a container (i.e. div) and set its display (to none and block) or it's visibility, or opacity (whichever floats your boat):

```
<div id="products">
   ....
</div>
```

JS:
    to hide:

```
document.GetElementById("products").style.display = "none";
```

to show:

```
document.GetElementById("products").style.display = "block";
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. why display and not visibility?

Comment: @FelixFarquharson well while setting visibility preserve the element place and just does not display it, setting display='none' won't display it and element's place would not be preserved (as if it is removed, sorry if my English is not very good). I don't know which one you prefer, so if you read my answer I have said that you can use visibility, display, opacity (which ever is best for your scenario) but i made the example with display because i had to choose one to set an example

Comment: ok thats a good explaination i tried with visibility and with block, no luck yet will update

Comment: i managed to make it work hiding individual divs with display but i was not able to use a container because the divs did not become visible again